# How to specify strings in Weka file?

Tags: classification, weka, document-classification

I am working on a text classification system and I would like to use unigrams as features. When building the arff file, I declared a string attribute field inside which I want to specify all the words contained in a message separated by comma. However, Weka is telling me that it "Cannot handle string attributtes". I tried defining the relation in the header with StringToWordVector, but it didn't help. How to go about this otherway? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your arff file format is correct then the following code can help you

```
 // dataSource: arff file (path of your arff file)

        BufferedReader trainReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataSource)); 
                       trainInsts = new Instances(trainReader); 
                       trainInsts.setClassIndex(trainInsts.numAttributes() - 1); 


        // the filter is used to convert the data from string to numeric 

                              StringToWordVector STWfilter = new StringToWordVector(); 
                              FilteredClassifier model = new FilteredClassifier(); 
                              model.setFilter(STWfilter); 

                           STWfilter.setInputFormat(trainInsts);  
// the converted data 
                           trainInsts = Filter.useFilter(trainInsts, STWfilter);
```